# group access to a Vbox-shared exFAT file

Tags: linux, virtualbox, tomcat

My problem is, that my tomcat user cannot access a file on a mounted exFAT drive.

Using a VM of Arch linux with kernel *6.1.12-1-MANJARO*.
The file to access shows up with ls:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 320 25. Feb 16:46 /home/'user'/share/tomcat/lib/jspwiki-custom.properties
```

*etc/group* contains the lines

```
vboxsf:x:109:tomcat
```

To test the access I do

```
sudo -u tomcat less /home/'user'/share/tomcat/lib/jspwiki-custom.properties
```

I get the response

```
/home/'user'/share/tomcat/lib/jspwiki-custom.properties: Permission denied
```

*/home/'user'/share* is the mount point for VBox to the exFAT folder.
The *VM Shared Folders* is configured as

- Path: F:\share
- Name: share
- Mount point: /home/'user'/share
- Auto-mount
- Make Permanent

*mount* command outputs the line

```
share on /home/'user'/share type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime)
```

Doing **exactly the same on a VM of Debian** linux with kernel *5.10.0-21-amd64* `sudo -u tomcat ...` shows the files content.
*mount* on Debian shows more options:

```
/home/'user'/share on /home/'user'/share type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,gid=999,dmode=0770,fmode=0770,tag=VBoxAutomounter)
```

How can I configure Arch 6.1.12 to behave like Debian 5.10.0? (Or could there be any other difference that I did not locate?)

Comment: What are the mount-options on both distros?

Comment: Check the output of `mount`

Comment: When you got it edit your question and add it there in code tags ....

Comment: edited my question

Comment: @TomYan as the VM-shared drive is extFAT, I can not change the owner and group. Full group access allowance shall do, and it does on Debian. Yes, both Linux run on the same VBox instance. Host is Win10.

Comment: Oh, ok Tom: I have not mounted the extFAT folder at all. VBox is doing that from the definition of *Shared Folders*. The definition is equal for *Arch* and *Debian*. The shown mount options are from entering *mount* command in a console.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `ls` output at the beginning. I hope that's really what you get on *Manjaro* though, and if it is, I suppose the problem here is that you can read and traverse all the directories in the shared folder, but cannot read any file, even when permission appears to be granted? (Btw, have you tried reading any other files? Also, are the files readable to root?)

Comment: I can't find any info on where/how to define the mount-options  ... but you could always unmount the shared folder in the gui, open a terminal and manually mount the shared folder in manjaro using the options from debian?  `mount -t vboxsf -o rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,gid=999,dmode=0770,fmode=0770 share /home/share`

Comment: @tom: you right: I can reduce the problem to do a *sudo -u tomcat ls /home/share". I get a *Permission denied there as well", but not on Debian.

Comment: That then probably means that `share` which manjaro showed in the mount line doesn't exist as such. Note the difference to the debian one.

Comment: I have to apologize. It works now, specifying VBox */home/share* as the mount point. What I have not mentioned above in the first place was, that I actually used */home/<user>/share* with my default user before, as the mount point. I thought it does not matter. It does not matter on *Debian* but it seems to matter on *Arch*. I am really sorry about my inaccuracy at this point.